# Can I install the 12.04 distribution in a docker container hosted by a 16.04 distribution

Tags: 12.04, 16.04, docker

I have a docker container hosted by 16.04 can I install a 12.04 distribution into this container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to install the image from scratch, I found [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278467/22558) where you can make docker to download the desired version and I adapted to my needs:

```
sudo docker run ubuntu:12.04 cat /etc/issue
```

returns this:

```
Unable to find image 'ubuntu:12.04' locally
12.04: Pulling from library/ubuntu
Downloading
...
Status: Downloaded newer image for ubuntu:12.04
Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS \n \l
```

or [alternatively](https://docs.docker.com/engine/quickstart/) you can use:

```
sudo docker pull ubuntu:12.04
```

and then run that image with

```
sudo docker run -i -t ubuntu:12.04 /bin/bash
```

to make sure in the prompt try to see the version:

```
cat /etc/issue
```

PS. Dont forget [to commit the changes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19586345/1577343), before exiting, otherwise are lost.
First get the container id using this command:

```
sudo docker ps -l
```

Commit changes to the container:

```
sudo docker commit <container_id> repo/img1
```

Then run the container:

```
sudo docker run -i -t repo/img1 /bin/bash
```